# Loading amcharts libraries in SAPUI5 - component.js vs index.html

Tags: sapui5, amcharts

I'm having trouble loading the amcharts libraries in SAPUI5. There are 3 amCharts libraries I want to load, core, charts and animated. I have them in my project structure in a folder called libs... please note that i want to use the component.js file not the index.html since my app will be launched from the Fiori Launchpad.

After some great advice I am now loading them in the manifest.json file like below

```
        "resources": {
            "js": [
                {
                    "uri": "libs/core.js"
        },
                        {
                    "uri": "libs/charts.js"
        },
                        {
                    "uri": "libs/animated.js"
        }
        ],

            "css": [
                {
                    "uri": "css/style.css"
                }
            ]
        },
```

when i test the app via the index.html file... it works!

when i test using the component.js file I get the following error in the console

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
The issue is most likely caused by application znrw.amCharts. Please create a support incident and assign it to the support component of the respective application. - Failed to load UI5 component with properties: '{
    "asyncHints": {
        "waitFor": []
    },
    "name": "znrw.amCharts",
    "url": "../../../../../webapp",
    "id": "application-Test-url-component",
    "componentData": {
        "startupParameters": {}
    },
    "async": true
}'. Error likely caused by:
TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null
```

[error in launchpad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGL7G.jpg)

so my question is, do I have to add something to the component.js file to get the libraries to load? or is there something more I need to do in the manifest.json file?

currently, the component file looks like this:

```
    "sap/ui/core/UIComponent",
    "sap/ui/Device",
    "znrw/amCharts/model/models"
], function (UIComponent, Device, models) {
    "use strict";

    return UIComponent.extend("znrw.amCharts.Component", {

        metadata: {
            manifest: "json"
        },

        /**
         * The component is initialized by UI5 automatically during the startup of the app and calls the init method once.
         * @public
         * @override
         */
        init: function () {
            // call the base component's init function
            UIComponent.prototype.init.apply(this, arguments);

            // enable routing
            this.getRouter().initialize();

            // set the device model
            this.setModel(models.createDeviceModel(), "device");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Does it work without the amcharts libraries imported? I don't know amcharts but if amCharts defines globally or does not support amd you might be better of loading them in the `resources` section of the manifest.

Comment: Yeah it does. Can you tell me how load them in the manifest? I didn’t know that was possible?

Answer (score 0):

In the `sap.ui` section of the manifest, you'll find an entry for `resources`. Generally it only has a CSS file in it but you can define external javascript libraries as well. If you're loading multiple dependent ones make sure to put them in order

```
    "resources": {
        "js": [{
            "uri": "libs/mylib.js"
        }],
        "css": [{
            "uri": "css/style.css",
            "id": "style"
        }]
    }
```

If all is well, you'll just be able to use `window.amChart` or whatever their global object is called

Comment: Awesome, I will try this tomorrow and post my results! Many thanks for your help :)

Comment: @NeilWard Yes you can add screenshots, that would be helpful

Comment: Hi Jorg, I've uploaded a screenshot of the error and I also updated the description of the problem as I've had further success. 
your suggestion of loading the libraries in the manifest I believe is a good one. now when I test my app with the index.html it works! however it doesn't work when I test it using the component.js (foiri lauchpad) and this is my ultimate goal.